# Adobe Animate Canvas infinite zoom

Tags: canvas, adobe-animate

I have many layers of SVG with different objects, starting from the universe down to the cellular level. Each of them are scaled down to acertain extend to simulate depth as each successive layer is further away. The idea is now, to animate in to the furthest layer but there is a limit on how much I can scale up in adobe animate.

Is there any strategy to position elements in the z axis without any limit? In canvas 3d transforms are deactivated.